# Many to Many relationships in Subsonic 3

Tags: sql, subsonic, many-to-many

I can't get this to work with Subsonic 3

I have two tables "Blog" & "Category" with a mapping (joining) table with a composite primary key on both Primary Keys.

I have looked into SQLServer.ttinclude and to my understanding, it doesnt handle many-to-many in the first place!

Comment: Looks like I have to move to NHibernate + some code generation tools like the following to generate ActiveRecord classes
http://www.darkside.co.za/archive/2010/08/18/t4-text-template-castle-activerecord.aspx
http://code.google.com/p/active-record-gen/
http://using.castleproject.org/display/Contrib/ActiveWriter
http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed
http://generatorstudio.codeplex.com/
http://retina.codeplex.com/
http://www.agilityfororms.com/Home/
http://dawliasoft.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationship properties will get created by the SubSonic template, but they will be from your Blog & Category tables to the joining table (rather than through to each other).

In one project, I made significant changes to the Classes & Context tt files in order to generate relationship properties across many-to-many tables.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I am getting from Subsonic which is counter intuitive.

Any chance of sharing your modifications back to subconic 3 github code? :) :) :)

Comment: No.  Unfortunately, no chance.  It's pretty specific to us, and I doubt it would be generally useful.  We're also taking SubSonic out of our toolbox due to a variety of issues.  I would however be happy to share the modified templates with you personally.

Comment: I guess taking Subsonic out is the right solution. The project looks like a dead end. I think all it needs is more contribution from the community, but the .NET community as we know it is less OSS minded than other communities such as Java or RoR.

Comment: I had my take on generating many to many but failed due to lack of time and would appreciate if I can look into your code to learn. How can I send you my private address? Are you on twitter? @korayem

Comment: I've sent you a message through your website.

Comment: Awesome man, I got it. A million thanks. I will look into it ASAP